# detect in rails if the user refresh the page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.0 and ruby 1.8.7

How could detect if the user refresh the browser page?

I am coding a web wizard form, so I go to next step if all is valid. However if the user refresh the page i don't want go to next step.

Update

I put a hidden field (I know about session solution) which is updated when the user submit the form. My problem is that the form has many steps.

Any idea?. Excuse me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually server shouldn't know anything about client's state, that's what REST was designed for.

Comment: @megas OK. I don't know this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually server shouldn't know anything about client's state, that's what REST was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it, you can use the flash object in order to detect when user refresh page.

For this purpose you need that the entry point of the page will be a redirect_to, so it makes things a little bit complicated, but at least it will solve your problem.